# making an animation by using setTimeout because I wanted add the delay on the animation but it behaves weirdly

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

so here's the code I wrote, as you can see when the trigger hits the red line, the boxes start changing the color to red, but when the trigger passes the red line again, some of the boxes turn the color to red again.

```js
function what() {
  const trigger1 = document.querySelector(".trigger1").getBoundingClientRect().y;
  const element = document.querySelectorAll(".ele");

  if (trigger1 < 100) {
    function why() {
      for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          element[i].classList.add('newColor');
        }, i * 500)
      }
    }

    why();
  } else {
    element.forEach((e) => {
      e.classList.remove('newColor');
    })
  }

}

window.addEventListener("scroll", what);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: rgb(134, 146, 211);
}

.newColor {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.line {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div>
      <h1 class="trigger1">here's the trigger</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="ele">ayyyo</li>
        <li class="ele">woooo</li>
        <li class="ele">yoooo</li>
        <li class="ele">loool</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div>
      <h1 class="trigger2">this is trigger 2</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

what I want to do is, when the trigger hits the red line, the boxes change the color to red.
After that when the trigger goes back (or leave the red line to bottom), the boxes change the color to the original color and never changes the color to red unless the trigger hits the red line again.

I might need to use clearTimeout thing but not sure where or how to put.

that'd be great if you let me know how I can solve this... thanks

Comment: Did you check my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable as timeout handler for clearTimeout.

Try following code.

```
var timeOutHandler = [];
function what() {
    const trigger1 = document.querySelector(".trigger1").getBoundingClientRect().y;
    const element = document.querySelectorAll(".ele");

    if(trigger1 < 100){
        for(let i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
            if ( typeof timeOutHandler[i] === 'undefined'){
                timeOutHandler[i] = setTimeout(()=> {
                    element[i].classList.add('newColor');
                }, i *500);  
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < timeOutHandler.length; i++ ){
            clearTimeout( timeOutHandler[i] );
            timeOutHandler[i] = undefined;
        }
        element.forEach((e) => {
            e.classList.remove('newColor');
        });
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", what);
```

Explanation:

According to your code, repeated setTimeout will executed everytime when user scroll.

To prevent repeated setTimeout, you can assign handler to every element, and execute setTimeout only when handler is undefined.
So, there will be only 1 setTimeout for every element when trigger hit red line for the first time.

And when trigger went back to below of red line, stop and remove all timeouts and assign undefined to all handlers.

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you so so much. It's bit hard to understand how I need to clear the timeout but it will help my study. (and hopefully I'll understand soon) anyways I appreciate you!!

Comment: Let me know which part is hard to understand for you? I will help you to understand. And if it is works, please vote & flag correct answer :)